# Sencha Touch - Store Not Parsing JSON Data

Tags: javascript, json, sencha-touch

I have a Store that gets JSON data from a WCF service. The store is calling the web service and getting data back, but my chart still displays no data, so I'm assuming it's not parsing it correctly.

**Here is my code:**

```
// Define Model
Ext.regModel('chart1model', {
    fields: [
        {name: 'name', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'data', type: 'string'}
    ]
});


var store1 = new Ext.data.Store({
    model: 'chart1model', 
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'http://localhost:8523/WebService/GetChartData?chartType=1',
        reader: {
            type: 'json'
        }
    },
    autoLoad: true
});
```

If I take the same data and create the Store myself, the chart displays correctly:

```
var store1 = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
        fields: ['name', 'data'],
        data: [
        {'name':'Nov-09','data':0},{'name':'Nov-10','data':0},{'name':'Nov-11','data':0},{'name':'Nov-12','data':0},{'name':'Nov-13','data':0},{'name':'Nov-14','data':0},{'name':'Nov-15','data':0},{'name':'Nov-16','data':0},{'name':'Nov-17','data':0},{'name':'Nov-18','data':0},{'name':'Nov-19','data':0},{'name':'Nov-20','data':0},{'name':'Nov-21','data':0},{'name':'Nov-22','data':0},{'name':'Nov-23','data':0},{'name':'Nov-24','data':0},{'name':'Nov-25','data':0},{'name':'Nov-26','data':0},{'name':'Nov-27','data':0},{'name':'Nov-28','data':0},{'name':'Nov-29','data':0},{'name':'Nov-30','data':0}
        ]
    });
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the JSON is being constructed correctly?

Comment: @LeandroBarreto - I'm fairly confident. In my second example, what comes after the "data:" identifier is exactly what is returned when calling the web service.

Comment: And you don't need to set the fields parameter in the request, also? The model is correct?

Comment: @LeandroBarreto in the examples I looked at you don't need to set it in the request, but I tried it anyways and still no luck.

Comment: Could you add the JSON data exactly as you retrieve it from the server.

Comment: @TDeBailleul That's essentially what I'm doing in the second example. Is there a way I can grab the JSON from the server and put it in a variable? That way I can see the output in javascript and not just in debug on the WCF service.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON data in your example has single quotes and that's not valid JSON. You can check your JSON data on http://www.jsonlint.com. Make sure you use double quotes in your JSON data.

Comment: It worked when I added it manually to the Store, but regardless I changed the string to use double quotes. It ran through the validator without error, but it's still not working with the Chart.

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified that the data ends up in the store?

Secondly, the data type for the "data" field is incorrect. It's obviously a number, but you've specified it as a string.

Comment: Yes the string was an error as a result of just trying random things. I changed it back to an int and still no luck. I'm fairly sure the data is not in the store. I'm not entirely sure how to verify that though.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was because it was coming back as a string and not as JSON. By casting it as JSON it worked:

```
return $.parseJSON(result);
```